# Conditional search NEST ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I have the following condition for a query that i should done with NEST.
Inside a list of objects, which has two fields: `Contract and RateId`

The condition:

> (Contract is not null) OR (Contract = 'contractX' && RateID is not null)

I've tried a lot of possible solutions using `Should, MustNot, Must` but I don't achieved.

Any idea?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#binary-and-operator

Comment: The condition `(Contract = 'contractX' && RateID is not null)` is a subset of `(Contract is not null)` i.e.  documents with `Contract = 'contractX'` will be matched by `(Contract is not null) `